# POST https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: polymer, disqus, shadow-dom

I use DISQUS in my polymer site, i got this error about three hundreds,and i checked [polymer-project.org](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/webview.html) ,it had the same problem.

```
POST https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**[polymer-project.org](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/webview.html)** **site:**

[image]

**my site:**:

[image]
[image]
and there are about three hundred requests!

I use [disqus-commnets](https://github.com/divshot/disqus-comments) element like this:

```
<core-header-panel mode="waterfall-tall" tallClass="medium-tall"  >
        <div  class="core-header ">{{response[0].title}}</div>
          <div layout horizontal center-justified flex class="contentcontainer">
            <div flex?="{{!phoneScreen}}"></div>
            <div vertical flex four style="background:#ffffff;box-shadow: 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19); color: #555;">
              <div flex  id="content" class="markdown-body"></div>
              <div flex><disqus-comments shortname="myName"></disqus-comments></div>
            </div>
            <div flex?="{{!phoneScreen}}"></div>
          </div>
      </core-header-panel>
```

What reason caused that?what did this error below indicate?

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://realtime.services.disqus.com/ws/2/thread/3704740536?' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

and ,DISQUS even not displayed on firefix,safari and IE,anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse it's called by the Skype Plugin (installed on chrome) thats why you see that XHR call only in google chrome.

Uninstall Skype Plugin.

Comment: yeah,they disappeared when skype plugin removed.

Answer (score 5):

The previous solution of disabling or uninstalling the Skype plugin may seem like a valid solution, but if your site is public facing it is anything but.
What you need is a permanent solution that works whether they have the plugin installed or not. The permanent solution is surprisingly easy once you know the trick.
All you have to do is add the following code snippet to the head of your website and it will stop Skype click to call from scanning the website outright!

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```